# Yii transaction not working

Tags: yii

i have code look like this:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $film->save();
        $idFilm = $film->id; //working at here
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->type = 1;
        $view->id_films = $idFilm;
        $view->view_at = date('Y-m-d');
        $view->save();//not working, not save view
        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
    }
```

but transaction not working, film is saved to the database even though the view is not saved to the database

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

When validation fails, it is not rising an Exception.

You should check if save has completed successfully, before committing transaction.

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
$rollback = false;
$exception = null;
try {
    if ($film->save()) {
        $idFilm = $film->id;
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->type = 1;
        $view->id_films = $idFilm;
        $view->view_at = date('Y-m-d');
        if ($view->save()) {
            $transaction->commit();
        }
        else {
            $rollback = true;
            echo CHtml::errorSummary($view); // Error output, if $view validation or saving failed
        }
    }
    else {
        $rollback = true;
        echo CHtml::errorSummary($film); // Error output, if $film validation or saving failed
    }
}
catch (CDbException $e) {
    $rollback = true;
    $exception = $e;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $rollback = true;
    $exception = $e;
}
if ($rollback) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
}
if (!is_null($exception)) {
    throw new Exception($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getCode());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if( ! $view->save()) {
    //$transaction->rollBack(); <---
    var_dump($view->getErrors());
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your code solves the problem, and not just have a code block.